# Google Script regex return list of matches pattern from details

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am using regex function in Google App Script to match specific pattern.

I want to extract `Item` details but I only managed to extract only first result.

I want to extract all matches

Code:

```
function item(input){
  var regExp = new RegExp("(Item:[^:]+)(?=\n)");
  var matches=new regExp(input);
  if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
    return matches[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Below is one of the cell (Column A) in google sheet i want to extract specific details.

Example:

```
Appointment Details
Date: XXXXXX
Time: XXXXXX
Type: XXXX
Service: xxxxx
Item: *XXXXXXX
XXXXX0001*
Total : XXXXXXXX

Date: XXXXXX
Time: XXXXXX
Type: XXXX
Service: xxxxx
Item: *XXXXXXX
XXXXX00123014*
Total : XXXXXXXX
```

I want to put the result in one cell (Column B)

Result:

```
Item: *XXXXXXX
XXXXX0001*
Item: *XXXXXXX
XXXXX00123014*
```

Comment: What do you mean by `var matches=new regExp(input);`? I don't think your function will return the first result either.

Comment: @Wiktor Don't think the post is duplicate.  For one thing, this post is about Google sheets and not docs.

Comment: @TheMaster The solution is the same: the regex should be compiled with the `g` flag. `RegExp` is the same in both.

Comment: @Wiktor There are couple of other issues as well. But I guess `/g` should be enough for op to get started.

Comment: `var rx = /°([^°]*)/g;
while (m=rx.exec(doc.getBody().getText())) { 
    Logger.log("Matched: " + m[1]);
}` Is it possible to use it for range of value? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Why use the regex from another answer? Use yours, `/(Item:[^:]+)(?=\n)/g` yields  `[20-01-26 13:13:11:110 CET] Matched: Item: *XXXXXXX
XXXXX0001*
[20-01-26 13:13:11:111 CET] Matched: Item: *XXXXXXX
XXXXX00123014*`